# Простой-простоволосый: какая связь?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Простой" — несложный, легкий. "Опростать" — высвободить. Отсюда, как я понимаю, "опростоволоситься". Но какая связь между этими словами, почему у них общий корень "прост"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какими словами? Простой и простоволосый? Нут так простые (не прикрытые) волосы. 
Вряд ли "опростоволоситься" напрямую связано с "опростать". Скорее уж - остаться без шапки. 
"Опростать" - немного другое значение - не просто освободить, но от содержимого. Правда, еще можно "опростать" ребенка, т.е. освободить его от пеленок, но тут тоже смысл доставания, освобождения "емкости" от содержимого.

А вот связано ли "простать" с "простым" -это уже другой вопрос. Понятно, что опростать - от "простой" в устаревшем значении "пустой", "порожний". Но родство это, видимо, настолько древнее, что современными носителями таковым не воспринимается.

Answer (score 2):

Появиться на людях без головного убора было когда-то для женщины большим позором. Отсюда и *опростоволоситься*.

Comment: А на мужчин-то как перенеслось?!

Comment: со временем...

Comment: Я не про то. Там, где женщине было положено покрывать голову, для мужчины как раз положено снимать головной убор. Смысл идиомы, если трактовать её подобным образом, вступает в противоречие с реалиями.

Comment: Возможно, опростоволосился - снял шапку по неосмотрительности, не в горнице, не в храме, не в присутственном месте, не перед начальством, а там, где не нужно было,или перед неважным человеком, то есть не сохранил достоинства.

Comment: А может быть, просто потерял(утратил как-то) шапку. А без шапки-то как быть?

Comment: Сдается мне, что здесь не связано с разовым недоразумением. Не снял, ну надел потом. А когда на церковь крестились - в самый лютый мороз шапки снимали. Не смертельно это. Вот если украли - это серьёзно. Зимой простоволосым домой бежать - это уже было бы надолго.

Comment: По-моему, связь современного значения с начальным очевидна. Не самый сложный случай.